# Best practices for implementing tool-tips in browser?

Tags: cross-browser, tooltip

I have a web project that was created primarily with Internet Explorer in mind. Tool-tips have been implemented in HTML by using the "Alt" attribute in various elements. I am finding that the tool-tip display is inconsistent when using Safari and Firefox.

What would be the best way to implement consistent tool-tips across all browsers? Is jQuery the best option or is their a better attribute to use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alt` attribute is not intended to be used as a tool-tip. it is to help with accessibility. search engines use them as well as screen readers and other devices to help handicapped people use the web. If you want a true tool-tip your best best is probably to use some javascript solution. jQuery has quite a few tool-tip plug-ins that are pretty easy to implement and I would start looking there. Just check out the [plug-in page](http://plugins.jquery.com) on jQuery's website

Comment: agreeing, but you forgot to mention the `title` attribute which is the correct way of describing/naming an image :)